# Adapting text inside in Donut Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot Donut plot with ggplot 2. Below you can see my data and also my plot.

```
test_data<-structure(list(KindOfParticipants = c("Participants", "Non-participants", 
                                          "Unknown group"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Total", class = "factor"), 
                          value = c(111L, 5937L, 18L), fraction = c(0.0431091877496671, 
                                                                    0.953894806924101, 0.00299600532623169), ymax = c(0.0431091877496671, 
                                                                                                                      0.997003994673768, 1), ymin = c(0, 0.0431091877496671, 0.997003994673768
                                                                                                                      ), labelPosition = c(0.0215545938748336, 0.520056591211718, 
                                                                                                                                           0.998501997336884), label = c("Participants\n value: 111", "Non-Participants\n value: 5937", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "Unknown group\n value: 110")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to plot Donut plot with this data.

```
plot_1_test<-ggplot(test_data, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, xmax=4, xmin=3, fill=KindOfParticipants)) +
  geom_rect() +
  geom_text( x=1, aes(y=labelPosition, label=label, color=variable), size=6) + # x here controls label position (inner / outer)
  scale_fill_brewer(palette=3) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette=3) +
  coord_polar(theta="y") +
  xlim(c(-1, 4)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
  ggtitle("Structure of participants or non participants or unkown groups")
plot_1_test
```

But these lines of code give me a Donut plot like the plot below :
[image]

So with this plot, I have two problems connected mainly with text inside the circle

First I want to have readable text inside the circle, now there is **overlapping of text** and second to have darker color inside the circle.

Can anybody help me with how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your label with `hjust` like below.

```r
require(ggplot2)

plot_1_test <- ggplot(test_data, aes(ymax=ymax, ymin=ymin, 
                      xmax=4, xmin=3, 
                      fill=KindOfParticipants)) +
  geom_rect()+ 
  # geom_label(x=3.5,aes(y=labelPosition, label=label),hjust=c(0,1,2))+
  geom_text(x=1, aes(y=labelPosition, label=label, 
                     color=KindOfParticipants), 
            size=5,
            hjust=c(-0.2,0.5,1)) + # x here controls label position (inner / outer)
  scale_fill_brewer(palette=3) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette=3)+
  coord_polar(theta="y")+
  xlim(c(-1, 4))+
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")+ 
  ggtitle("Structure of participants or non participants or unkown groups")
plot_1_test
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>